# Bootstrap CSS only working in PC web browser and not mobile browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm new to the bootstrap framework. I have site that looks like this in the browser...
[image]

But this on mobile browsers...

[image]

All the stack posts I'm reading say the issue is with the viewport meta tag, but I believe I have that correct, below is the header for my code.

```
<head>
    <title> Matt & El </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Any Ideas of what else it could be? I can provide the full source code if need be. For reference my browser is google chrome, and I've tried both Safari and Bing for mobile browsers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading Bootstrap content from an insecure location (`http`) instead of `https`. Modern browsers disallow loading content from insecure sources when the page itself is `https` (which the lock symbol from your mobile screenshot indicates).

So replace `http` with `https` (maxcdn redirects the requests to `https` anyway):

```html
<head>
    <title> Matt & El </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: He should probably be using protocol relative urls right? `//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com` instead of `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com` or `http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com`

Comment: In a secure environment, it's never a bad idea to explicitly request from `https`.

Comment: 100% true and good practice, but we aren't sure that his site doesn't serve http and https versions of the site. That's the only reason I asked.

Comment: Perfect that was the exact fix I was looking for.